# How can I convert from user input image to URL in react

Tags: html, reactjs

I'm taking an image as an input from user using the below code
`<input type="file" onChange={this.fileUpload}/>`

I want to convert the image into URL.

This is what I used in `fileUpload()` function

```
fileUpload = (event) => {
   let src = event.target.value.getAsDataURL();
   this.setState({
     image: src
   });
 }
```

Please let me know how to convert image into URL.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?  This is almost never a good idea.  You can use the file client-side for whatever you need, and you can upload it to the server as binary.  So, why waste all the resources and the 33% overhead making it base-64?

Comment: I need to send the URL through a post method to an API. It accepts only URL.

Comment: Fix your API... it should accept binary.  Much m ore efficient.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function below as ImageChange function and use the state variable imagePreviewUrl to preview the image.

```
    _handleImageChange(e) {

    let reader = new FileReader();
    let file = e.target.files[0];

    reader.onloadend = () => {
      this.setState({
        file: file,
        imagePreviewUrl: reader.result
      });
    }

    reader.readAsDataURL(file)
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `ref` to your input tag, so you can access the dom for that element:

`<input type="file" ref={this.myFiles} onChange={this.fileUpload}/>`

```
fileUpload=()=>{
    // Now get files in the FileList object
    const files = this.myFiles.files
    // Define what type of file to accept:
    const accept = ["image/png"];
    if (accept.indexOf(files[0].mediaType) > -1) {
       this.setState({
           image: files[0].getAsDataURL()
       })
    }

 }
```

More infos: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/getAsDataURL

Comment: Its throwing an error,   `TypeError: Cannot read property 'files' of undefined`

Comment: probably a problem with scope, please post your code

Comment: instead of `const files = this.myFiles.files`   i used `const files = event.target.files` . Its working now. Thanks for the help